# Data not visible in plotly rangeslider

Tags: python, visualization, plotly, gantt-chart

I'm using Plotly with Python and pandas df to create a gantt-chart with a rangeslider. However, the data on rangeslider is not visible and instead of appearing with the colors as in the actual plot, it appears white-colored.

Here is part of the code I'm using:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

colors = {0: 'rgb(46, 137, 205)',
              1: 'rgb(58, 149, 136)',
              2: 'rgb(114, 44, 121)'}
fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='num_faces', show_colorbar=True,
                          bar_width=0.2, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True, group_tasks=True)

fig['layout']['xaxis']['rangeselector']['visible'] = False
fig['layout']['xaxis']['rangeslider'] = dict(bgcolor='#000')
fig['layout']['xaxis']['type'] = 'date'
# yaxis customisation
fig['layout']['yaxis']['title'] = 'Number of people'
# plot customisation
fig['layout']['title'] = 'Time Spent with People'
```

Just for display options, I have set the background color of the `rangeslider` to black and here is the plot result. As you see, data is there but not colored.

[image]
Is there any solution on how to make my data visible on the rangeslider?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using plotly v.2.2.1 and Python 3.5.2.